# How to pass data from webview back to the native Android app

Tags: android, webview

Our Android app has a WebView which shows a page from our web-server. The page does a user registration (either via Facebook or by choosing a username and password). After that, I want the page to pass information back to the native app (e.g., username, license type, messges, etc.).

I know of JavaScript<->Java binding (addJavaScriptInterface), but was wondering is there a different way do to it:

Comment: I'm working on an app that needs to do the same (pass information submitted in a webview form back to the Java native app) to store bits of user info on the device's internal storage. Just wondering if you ever found a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

After the user logs in, you can capture data from the URL using WebView::getUrl().  Alternately, you could use cookies.

http://pragungoyal.com/tutorials/extracting-cookies-from-a-webview-in-android/